# Tool to convert string into XML safe string

Tags: android, xml, string

I have the following string:

> Here's the thing. You said a "mountain lion is a lion."
>   Is it in the same family? Yes. No one's arguing that.
>   As someone who is a scientist who studies lions, I am telling you, specifically, in science, no one calls mountain lions "lions". If you want to be "specific" like you said, then you shouldn't either. They're not the same thing.
>   If you're saying lion family" you're referring to the taxonomic grouping of Felidae, which includes things from house cats to ocelots to tigers.
>   So your reasoning for calling a mountain lion a lion is because random people "call the big ones lions?" Let's get panthers and leopards in there, then, too.
>   Also, calling someone a human or an ape? It's not one or the other, that's not how taxonomy works. They're both. A mountain lion is a mountain lion and a member of the lion family. But that's not what you said. You said a mountain lion is a lion, which is not true unless you're okay with calling all members of the lion family lions, which means you'd call house cats, tigers, and other cats lions, too. Which you said you don't.
>   It's okay to just admit you're wrong, you know?

That I want to convert into a properly formatted string to put in my strings.xml file.

I tried using the following tools:

http://coderstoolbox.net/string/#!encoding=xml&action=encode&charset=none
http://www.freeformatter.com/xml-escape.html#ad-output

but each time I built my project I got the following error:

> Error:(39, 5) Apostrophe not preceded by \ (in Here's the thing. You said a "mountain lion is a lion."

What can I do?

Also what is odd is that all the apostrophes in the string have been replaced by
    `&apos;`
So I'm not sure why I am still getting that error. When I manually put a `\` in front of every `&apos;` it was fine but that is very inconvenient. I would like to automate this process.

Answer (score 1):

Start with your original string. Replace all `'` with `\'`. Replace all `"` with `\"`. Use that as the value of your string resource.

You wind up with:

```
<resources>
  <string name="whatevs">Here\'s the thing. You said a \"mountain lion is a lion.\" Is it in the same family? Yes. No one\'s arguing that. As someone who is a scientist who studies lions, I am telling you, specifically, in science, no one calls mountain lions \"lions\". If you want to be \"specific\" like you said, then you shouldn\'t either. They\'re not the same thing. If you\'re saying lion family\" you\'re referring to the taxonomic grouping of Felidae, which includes things from house cats to ocelots to tigers. So your reasoning for calling a mountain lion a lion is because random people \"call the big ones lions?\" Let\'s get panthers and leopards in there, then, too. Also, calling someone a human or an ape? It\'s not one or the other, that\'s not how taxonomy works. They\'re both. A mountain lion is a mountain lion and a member of the lion family. But that\'s not what you said. You said a mountain lion is a lion, which is not true unless you\'re okay with calling all members of the lion family lions, which means you\'d call house cats, tigers, and other cats lions, too. Which you said you don\'t. It\'s okay to just admit you\'re wrong, you know?</string>
</resources>
```

Comment: The problem is I want to automate this process.

Comment: @Roymunson: String replacement has been around since COBOL, if I recall correctly. Please name a modern programming language, higher than assembler, that does not offer the equivalent of Java's `replaceAll("'","\'")` and such.

Comment: I was looking for a online tool that could do it for me. But since it is so easy to program I'll make a quick solution myself.

Comment: Notepad will do.  Find | Replace, replace ' with \'

Answer (score 0):

CommonsWare provided an answer of putting a slash before every ` and ".

I made a simple Java program that will do this from a textfile:

```
    import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
        //Put the string you want formatted here.
          BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

        String input = "EMPTY STRING";
        File



inputFile = new File("[Path to File]");

        input = stringToFile(inputFile);

       input = input.replace("\'", "\\\'");
       input = input.replace("\"", "\\\"");

        System.out.println("Output:");
        System.out.println(input);


    }




public static String stringToFile(File filename) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
      try (BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filename)))
        {
            return in.lines().collect(Collectors.joining("\n"));
        }
} 

}
```